# Continuity in the Stone–Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology

Let be $(X,  \tau)$ a compact and Hausdorff topological space, and let be $(x_n)_n \subseteq X$, a sequence of elements of X. I need to prove that the function $g:  \beta\mathbb{N}\rightarrow{}X$ defined by $g(F)=\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{}F}{} x_n$ is continuous.

I have $ \beta\mathbb{N}=\left\{{F\subseteq \mathbb{N}: F \text{ is an ultrafilter on } \mathbb{N}}\right\}$ and for $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, we defined $[A]:=\left\{{P \in{}  \beta\mathbb{N}: A \in{} P}\right\}\subseteq\beta\mathbb{N}$, and we know that $ \digamma:=\left\{{[A]: A \subseteq \mathbb{N}}\right\}\subseteq \mathbb{P}(\beta\ \mathbb{N})$ is a basis for a topology on $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Also, I know that for any $F \in{}  \beta\mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n \to{}F}{} x_n$ exist and it's unique because X is a compact and Hausdorff topological space. Then $g$ is well defined.

Comment: Just explaining my edits: A filter is a subset of the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$, not a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. And to put plain text in math mode, you should wrap it in \text{}.

Comment: Why did you change @AlexKruckman's correction, with the ultrafilters $F$ being subsets of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, back to the incorrect version where the ultrafilter is said to be a subset of $\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an open set in $X$. We want to show $g^{-1}[U]$ is open. For each $F\in g^{-1}[U]$, it suffices to find a neighborhood $\widehat{U}$ of $F$ in $\beta\mathbb{N}$ such that $\widehat{U}\subseteq g^{-1}[U]$.

In $X$, use compactness to find a pair of disjoint open sets $U'$ and $V$ such that  $g(F) \in U'\subseteq U$ and $(X\setminus U)\subseteq V$ (compact Hausdorff spaces are $T_4$: any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by disjoint open sets). Let $A = \{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid x_n\in U'\}$, and let $\widehat{U} = [A]$. Since $U'$ is an open neighborhood of $g(F)$, $A\in F$, so $F\in \widehat{U}$. It remains to show that $g[\widehat{U}]\subseteq U$.

Indeed, suppose for contradiction that $F'\in \widehat{U}$ (so $A\in F'$), but $g(F')\notin U$. Then $g(F') \in V$. Let $B = \{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid x_n\in V\}$. Then also $B\in F'$, but since $U'$ and $V$ are disjoint, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so $\emptyset\in F'$, contradiction.

By the way, this exercise is just the [universal property of $\beta\mathbb{N}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Universal_property_and_functoriality).

Comment: Sorry, my original answer was wrong. I've fixed it.

Comment: @dajc By the way, it looks like you're new to the site, and you haven't accepted any answers yet. If you receive an answer you're satisfied with, click the small check mark below the up/down arrows to the left of the answer to accept the answer.